# coalesce with multiple case when condition with sum of numeric measures that must be > 0 or < 0.80

Tags: sql-server

I am building a report in a view in sql and i would like to take 1 when the following conditions are met otherwise null. Then, i would like to make a count of how many 1 have been considered in the table
Thanks

```
        coalesce(case WHEN (sum(SAFETY_STOCK) > 0 and
 ((sum(PROJECTED_STOCK_ON_HAND) / sum(SAFETY_STOCK) > 0) 
    or (sum(PROJECTED_STOCK_ON_HAND)/sum(SAFETY_STOCK)) < 0.8)  ) then 1.0 ) end)  as ZERO_SS_80,
```

Comment: To count the number of 1s you just need to envelop it within a SUM function.

Comment: the problem is that if i add a sum sql server is not able to use aggregate functions within subqueries

Comment: with MyQuery as ( xxx_your_current_query_xxx ) select sum(ZERO_SS_80) from MyQuery

Comment: Thank you, could you advice where the query is wrong in terms of parenthesis?

Comment: It should work. Why don't you post your entire query and see if there could be a problem to use it as a CTE ?. I have added my proposal as an answer

Comment: ok  `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 114
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
 `

Comment: It seems that the or condition is not supported within the case when statement. Can it be possible?

Comment: If you show us your entire SQL, I could tell you what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your current query as a CTE, and sum its ZERO_SS_80 column.

```
with MyCTE as ( 
   select ...  /* Here goes your whole current query */
          ... 
          ... as ZERO_SS_80
    from ...
    group by ...          
) 
select sum(ZERO_SS_80) 
from MyCTE
```